# Add dropdown filter list to ggplot in RMarkdown HTML file WITHOUT using shiny?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm creating an HTML file with RMarkdown that contain's some interactive plots. With some help, I got to create a dropdown list to filter a variable that changes the plot, but it uses shiny so I can't render it to an HTML file. Is there any way I can add a dropdown list without using shiny so I can have my HTML file?

The code:

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

# data
data <- data.frame(
  anoobito = sample(2019:2023),
  diadasemana = sample(c("Segunda", "Terça", "Quarta", "Quinta", "Sexta", "Sábado", "Domingo"), 23000, replace = TRUE)
)

dia <- data %>%
  group_by(anoobito, diadasemana) %>%
  tally %>%
  mutate(diadasemana = factor(diadasemana, levels = c("Domingo","Segunda", "Terça", "Quarta", "Quinta", "Sexta", "Sábado")))

# Create a ggplot object
gg <- ggplot(dia, aes(x = diadasemana, y = n, group = anoobito)) +
      geom_line(aes(color = anoobito), size = 2) +
      geom_point(aes(color = anoobito), size = 3) +
      theme_minimal(base_size = 15) +
      scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,1000), expand = expansion(mult = c(0, .1))) +
      theme(legend.position = "bottom",
            axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
            axis.text.x=element_text(colour="black"), axis.text.y=element_text(colour="black")) +  
      labs(
        x = "Ano do Óbito", # label do eixo X
        y = "Número de Óbitos",
        caption = "**Fonte**: SIM, SMS-RJ. Dados sujeitos a alterações.") 

# Create a plotly object from ggplot
p <- ggplotly(gg)

# Add a dropdown list for the variable "anoobito"
p <- p %>% layout(showlegend = F,
  updatemenus = list(
    list(
      x = 1.5,
      y = 0.8,
      buttons = list(
        list(method = "restyle",
             args = list("visible", list(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)),
             label = "2019"),
        list(method = "restyle",
             args = list("visible", list(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)),
             label = "2020"),
        list(method = "restyle",
             args = list("visible", list(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)),
             label = "2021"),
        list(method = "restyle",
             args = list("visible", list(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)),
             label = "2022"),
        list(method = "restyle",
             args = list("visible", list(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)),
             label = "2023")
      )
    )
  )
)

p
```

It looks weird. I want to delete the legend and when I select 2019, it should only appear 2019 and not all of the years. The plot isn't showing geom_point.

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate more on *"The plot isn't showing geom_point."* I see points and lines. You could comment out the `geom_point()` layer and compare the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don´t see the `geom_point()` when a year is selected, right?
GGplot is considering `anoobito` as continuous. Try to make them factors, just like `diadasemana`:

```
dia <- data %>%
  group_by(anoobito, diadasemana) %>%
  tally %>%
  mutate(
    anoobito = factor(anoobito, levels = 2019:2023),
    diadasemana = factor(diadasemana, levels = c("Domingo","Segunda", "Terça", "Quarta", "Quinta", "Sexta", "Sábado")))
```

You´ll get this:
[image]

..and your `geom_point()` when selecting a year:
[image]

PS. Beware of spaghetti graphics!