# How to add dropdown filter list to ggplotly without using Shiny?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

The code is as below:

```
{r, knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)}
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)


#sample data
result_table = structure(list(wave = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L), term = c(1L, 
       2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), estimate = c(3.317, 0.887, 1, 0.828, 0.995, 
       1), Std.Error = c(1.249, 1.044, 1, 1.04, 1.003, 1), Statistic = c(10.305, 
       -1.571, 1, -3.297, -0.96, 1), P.Value = c(1, 1.01, 1, 1, 1.05, 
       1), conf.low = c(2.829, 0.802, 1, 0.749, 0.989, 1), conf.high = c(3.806, 
       0.973, 1, 0.906, 1, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
       -6L))
result_table$wave %<>% as.factor
result_table$term %<>% as.factor
gg <- ggplot(result_table, aes(x = wave,  y = estimate,group = term)) +
      geom_point(aes(color = wave), size = 2) +
      geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=conf.low, ymax=conf.high,color = wave), 
                        linewidth=.1) + 
      geom_hline(yintercept = 0) + 
      labs(color = "Wave") +
      ylab('Estimate') +
      xlab('Term') +
      theme_classic() 

# Create a plotly object from ggplot
p <- ggplotly(gg)

p <- p %>% layout(showlegend = F,
  updatemenus = list(
    list(
      x = 1.5,
      y = 0.8,
#      yanchor = "bottom",
#      xanchor = 'center',
      buttons = list(
        list(method = "restyle",
             args = list("visible", list(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)),
             label = "1"),
        
        list(method = "restyle",
             args = list("visible", list(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)),
             label = "2"),
        
        list(method = "restyle",
             args = list("visible", list(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)),
             label = "3")
      )
    )
  )
)

p
```

The result is :
[image]

In the graph, I would like to make the variable `term` as a dropdown list, so that I can select the item in `term` and update the plot instantly. However, plotly plotted all the item in `term` in the same time, what can I do to fix this problem?

I used the code from
[Add dropdown filter list to ggplot in RMarkdown HTML file WITHOUT using shiny?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77483158/add-dropdown-filter-list-to-ggplot-in-rmarkdown-html-file-without-using-shiny),
why his code could work well but the code of mine could not work well?

Is it because of geom_errorbar?

Comment: You need multiple traces. This does not work with `group` or `color` alone. Meaning you need to create multiple `geom` for each group. It is a bit counterintuitive when thinking in R world, but `plotly` comes from Javascript. I know I have seen a duplicate for this somewhere.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but why https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77483158/add-dropdown-filter-list-to-ggplot-in-rmarkdown-html-file-without-using-shiny can work...?

Comment: He/She also used `ggplotly` with `color` and `group`.

Comment: Seems it works with color in the individual geoms but not group/color in the main ggolot aes. It is very late at night/early in the morning for me, and I wouldn't have been up if I didn't have a deadline (yes, SO is my coffee break, how sad, lol). I will reopen for now, and will take a look tmrw to see if I can help further. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out by @M-- in the comments, `plotly` thinks in traces. And to make your filter work requires to have separate for each `term`. I tried to get this right using the `group` aes but failed. Instead one option to get separate traces would be to add the geom layers separately for each value of `term` by filtering the data. To avoid duplicating code I use `lapply`. This way the layers or traces are added as groups of 4 traces per `term`, i.e. the first four traces are for `term=1` and so on. Hence, you also have to account for that when you set the visibility of the traces in `updatemenus`:

```
library(plotly)

gg <- ggplot(result_table, aes(
  x = wave,
  y = estimate,
  color = wave,
  group = term
)) +
  lapply(levels(result_table$term), \(x) {
    list(
      geom_point(data = ~ subset(.x, term == x), size = 2),
      geom_errorbar(
        data = ~ subset(.x, term == x),
        aes(ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high),
        linewidth = .1
      )
    )
  }) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
  labs(color = "Wave") +
  ylab("Estimate") +
  xlab("Term") +
  theme_classic()

# Create a plotly object from ggplot
p <- ggplotly(gg)

library(plotly)

p <- p %>% layout(
  showlegend = F,
  updatemenus = list(
    list(
      x = 1.5,
      y = 0.8,
      buttons = list(
        list(
          method = "restyle",
          args = list(
            "visible",
            c(rep(TRUE, 4), rep(FALSE, 4), rep(FALSE, 4), TRUE)
          ),
          label = "1"
        ),
        list(
          method = "restyle",
          args = list(
            "visible",
            c(rep(FALSE, 4, 4), rep(TRUE, 4), rep(FALSE, 4), TRUE)
          ),
          label = "2"
        ),
        list(
          method = "restyle",
          args = list(
            "visible",
            c(rep(FALSE, 4, 4), rep(FALSE, 4), rep(TRUE, 4), TRUE)
          ),
          label = "3"
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

p
```

[image]

Comment: 'I tried to get this right using the group aes but failed.' Do you think it is a bug of plotly?

Comment: Nop. I think `ggplotly´ does a great job. But it's not perfect and in the end ggplot2 and plotly are two different things.